# Get password from pbkdf2-sha256 hash having the salt and the number of iterations

Tags: sha256, pbkdf2

I have the hash, the salt and the number of iterations and need to get the original password.

Is there an online tool to get the password from the pbkdf2-sha256 hash given the salt and number of iterations?

I have found online some tools that generate the hash given the password, salt and number of iterations but not the other way round.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not within a reasonable time.
The idea behind cryptographic hash functions is, that they are easy in one direction (Clear text to hash) but incredibly hard the other way around.

What you do to verify a password is you hash the entered clear password and then compare the hashes. You don't "unencrypt" the stored password hash and compare the clear text.

You can read more about cryptographic hashes application in password verification [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function#Password_verification)

There are some methods to attack hashed passwords. Most notably the brute-force attack, where you try out passwords, then hash them and compare against the given hash. You can improve on that attack using a dictonary attack, where you narrow down the search space by using a dictonary because many people use words instead of random characters.

Comment: Thanks for the response. If I generate a hash from a certain password, with a certain salt and number of iterations and after that I try to generate a hash with the same password, salt and number of iterations it will always generate the same hash?

Comment: I am asking this because I thought it should always give the same hash.
But the result of hashing the password "password" with the salt "2G6Pax9Qrt7PA1PlLbYk6s==" and number of iterations 20000 gives different hashes on the online tools https://www.freecodeformat.com/pbkdf2.php and https://onlinephp.io/hash-pbkdf2.
It gives an hash of ddc94a38dd65dc2c9ce183708802e55b5f668537c811ae444b5c5d2256ecfdff on the first and of b39efb4dd4c22d9f1e15b790fd30804d22357ceb3199062c865032c14f094d81 on the last one.

Comment: @JoãoValente The result depends on the exact input parameters and the encoding of these. Specially the salt might be tricky as it could be a byte array, a string or even a base64 encoded string. Also the selected hashing algorithm is important (one of your linked pages can select one, the other one use a hard coded algorithm). But when you call the functions/methods with the same arguments, you will get the same result.